# Screen turns off while installing debian or ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, debian, installation

I'm trying to setup a server on a slightly old-ish system with an Intel E2220 CPU and a Radeon graphics card (don't have the model on hand). I tried debian, both 32 and 64bit, aswell as ubuntu server, but with all 3, the screen turns off during the partitioning wizard (BEFORE applying the changes!!!)
This happens in both text and graphic installs, but it doesn't ever happen in either Windows XP or Linux Mint (both already installed). Running gparted on Mint works, too. The PC itself is still on and responds to Capslock and such.

I have no idea what could cause this and haven't found anything online.

Comment: Try booting with "acpi=off" and see if that helps. In ubuntu you should be able to select this from boot menu with f6 if I remember right ;)

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turned out to be a hardware problem. Switching to onboard graphics solved the problem.